# Open link in webview, using firebase in app messaging

Tags: ios, swift, webview

My app is a webview app.

Please, explain me, how to open link in my webview app when I press "Открыть" button?

Now, when I press the button, link redirects and opens in Safari.

The message appears via firebase in app messaging.

Thank you.

```
import JXWebViewController
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInAppMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm_message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let url = URL(string: "https://kupi95.ru/")!

        let webViewController = JXWebViewController()
        webViewController.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))


        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = webViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // Register the delegate with the InAppMessaging instance
        let myFiamDelegate = CardActionFiamDelegate()
        InAppMessaging.inAppMessaging().delegate = myFiamDelegate;

        return true
    }


    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo)

      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know abouuserNotificationCentert the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert])
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
  }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
      print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

      let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
      print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
}
```

import Foundation
import FirebaseInAppMessaging
import JXWebViewController

class CardActionFiamDelegate : NSObject, InAppMessagingDisplayDelegate {

```
func messageClicked(_ inAppMessage: InAppMessagingDisplayMessage, with action: InAppMessagingAction) {
    // ...
    let webViewController = JXWebViewController()
    webViewController.webView.load(URLRequest(url: action.actionURL))
}

func messageDismissed(_ inAppMessage: InAppMessagingDisplayMessage,
                      dismissType: FIRInAppMessagingDismissType) {
    // ...
}

func impressionDetected(for inAppMessage: InAppMessagingDisplayMessage) {
    // ...
}

func displayError(for inAppMessage: InAppMessagingDisplayMessage, error: Error) {
    // ...
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you show code, how you try do this?

Comment: [link] https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=ios
I follow this instruction

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't answer for question. How exactly you try do this?
Can you send your code? Or smth else?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct.
It link, can help you:
[firebase doc about modify message behavior](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/modify-message-behavior?platform=ios)

Look like it can do with func `messageClicked` [InAppMessagingDisplayDelegate messageclicked](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseinappmessaging/api/reference/Protocols/InAppMessagingDisplayDelegate#messageclicked_:with:):

```
func messageClicked(_ inAppMessage: InAppMessagingDisplayMessage, with action: InAppMessagingAction) {
    // open view controller with webview for action.actionURL
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your solution but it didn't work. Please, look at my code, I pasted it

Comment: You should debug your code it, look like you just make JXWebViewController with link. And don't show it.

let webViewController = JXWebViewController()
    webViewController.webView.load(URLRequest(url: action.actionURL))

if you click func messageClicked called?

Comment: I didn't understand what should I do. Please, explain me in other words my steps

Comment: You should debug how work your code, what happen if you click cell? Do run func messageClicked?